# How to turn on laptop with external power button

Tags: laptop, power

I want to turn a laptop into a desktop computer by connecting it to a monitor and mouse & keyboard, however, it is very annoying to have to open and close the lid every time i want to turn it on... is there anything i can do to turn it on externally, like a usb power button or extend the existing button outside the computer. Of course, i could remove the creen, but it would be a pitty to remove a perfectly working screen just to gain access to the power button :) haha!

I would ideally like to place it under the screen, closed lid, which would make it even more inconvinient to open and close to turn on...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684013/wake-up-pc-on-usb

Comment: Purchase a docking station.  Don't modify your laptop you will break it.

Comment: I had to re-read this description a couple times to understand what was being asked. My initial response to the question in the title was to just say "press the button." :-)

Comment: To add on the answer pointed to by @50-3. It would mean that first you need to configure your BIOS to wake up from keyboard (or USB, or PS/2) (that might not be possible depending on laptop model) and it would mean the computer *might* wake up as soon as you connect your input device to the laptop. You have been warned.